# How do i join 2 substring indexes in Query Builder?

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

So i have 2 RAW Substring indexes in my query builder which i need to join together. These values are used for exporting to excel.

So this is the code i have.

```
public function collection()
{
        'bookings.user_fullname',
        DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_fullname, ' ', 1) AS Firstname"),
        DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_fullname, ' ', 2) AS MiddleName"),
        DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_fullname, ' ', 3),' ',-1) AS Lastname"),
}
```

So i want the middle name and last name to be joined together instead of them being on seperate columns. For example a name "John Oliver Smith" would be seperated as "John" and "Oliver Smith". Or even a longer name like "Mark Andrew Philip Man" as "Mark" and "Andrew Philip Man".

So basically name on one column and the rest of the values on different column. Any idea how i can do that?

Comment: DB::raw('CONCAT(user_middle_name, ", ", user_last_name) AS full_name'


                            Change the name of the fields as the one in your database

Comment: The thing is that i do not have the middle name and last name stored in different columns, they are under bookings.fullname, which contians the full name and i have to split the names from there.

Comment: If `DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_fullname, ' ', 1) AS Firstname")` is the first part you want then `DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_fullname, ' ', -1) AS Firstname")` would be the rest of the string right?